# Are PS+ free games region-locked?

Tags: ps4, psn, region-lock

1. I have a PSN account that belongs to region X.
2. It has a PS+ subscription.
3. I have acquired many games throughout the years; some are PS+ free games, some are digital medias bought from PS Store.
4. I'm moving to region Y.

Question: will I be able to play all of them normally on while I'm in region Y, specially those free PS+?

In other words, will I be able to keep using the same PSN and PS+ accounts and get access to my games in the library?

PS: I believe it is not possible to change country of a PSN account, isn't that so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not require a region Y account to use your region X content in region Y.

You can continue to purchase and play on your region X account from region Y with no problems and as long as you maintain a valid payment method for region X. I know this because I am doing it and have been for many years.

If you want to purchase content that is specific for region Y you will have to create a region Y account in order to access the local store.

You will also need to be cautious with DLC, if you buy a physical copy of a game in region Y it may not be compatible with DLC downloaded from the region X store. The physical copy of the game will work with your region X account just fine.

So you may want to create a region Y account for the specific reasons above but you do not need to have one, all your existing content will still be accessible.

Comment: Note that movies are region-locked on PSN.

Answer (score 1):

You will continue having the games, being able to play them, but in order to get Y country new games, you will need a Y country account, not all the games are in the same  countries.

Comment: Basically, in order to keep my old games AND buy new ones, I would have to create a new account AND keep the old one?

Comment: Thats right. U can have more than 1 acc in a ps

Comment: Yep, I know that, but it seems to me that would need 2 accs, both of them having a PS+, which would be a waste imo

Comment: Just keep the original account. The only trick will be you have to change to paying for games and your subscription via pre-paid cards.

Comment: The downvoter, if you dont post a comment saying the aswer is bad, I can't correct it. Plus as @colin sayed, you need an acc on the new region to purchase that region new games so,  manifest oh downvoter!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the answer is not correct.  You don't have to get an account for the new country.  You can just continue using your old account and continue to get new PS+ games with it.  The only issue is that the games that are free with PS+ are sometimes different by region.  You're probably best off keeping the original account,  as if you make a new one for the country you are in and use that to subscript to PS+, you'll lose access to the old games.

Comment: @ Kek, I did downvote as your answer is, at best ambiguous and are worst wrong. You do not need a new account to continue purchasing games. I provided my own answer which, in my opinion, is a better explanation than your single sentence answer.  I figured it was obvious that was what happened since the downvote and new answer both appeared at the same time on a 4 month old question.

Comment: You cant purchase new Y country games on your X country account. As you said. Maybe ambigous yes, but not wrong. Maybe it need an edit to precise what i wanted to say, Thanks :)